# Wormhole attack in IoT using NetSim by TetCos

Tags: security, networking, routes, simulation, iot

I am using NetSim by Tetcos to simulate Wormhole attacks in IoT networks that rely on RPL as routing protocol.
To do so I need two IoT devices to communicate with each other even if they are not linked directly in the DODAG structure. Therefore my theoretical solution would be to set up a wired link between the two malicious nodes and to do so I would need to set up a second interface in the IoT device which is not available by default.
Is there anyone of you who know how to implement this or that can help me in any way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I never used NetSim, but I am an RPL expert. I have some questions:
1. If you have only two nodes-both attackers-what are they going to attack?
2. If they are not on the same DAG, then how are they going to communicate? This usually means that they are beyond the link coverage.

Comment: @John Fixon Thank for your reply. I am more than glad to clarify your doubts: 1. I do not have only 2 IoT nodes, I am implementing a scenario with more than 30 nodes and 2 of them are the malicious nodes which form the wormhole attack for this particular scenario. 2. In NetSim it is possible to simulate only 1 DODAG at the time therefore the two nodes belong to the same tree. Moreover I made sure that the two malicious nodes are close enough to be in range of communication (they are also neighbours (but not father and son) in the DODAG).

Comment: Why wired link? There is a wireless 802.15.4, where the RPL relies, correct?

Comment: Yeah correct, I can either use wireless or wired link, the problem itself is not the type of link to be used but how to set it up in such a way that packets can be delivered also to nodes which are not parent nodes.

Comment: If I get it correctly, you are asking for what the RPL does not do! RPL is a point to multipoint, i.e., all nodes communicate with the sink, NOT with other nodes. If a node is a parent (or a parents' parent) it will forward data messages "up the ladder" until it reaches the sink. If you want point-to-point communcations in RPL, you need extra solution like this:  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8832178

Comment: I soved the issue and I was able to implement the wormhole attack in the end. Thank you very much for your help in any case @JohnFixon

Comment: Please answer briefly your own question for helping others.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the help of NetSim support. I was able to implement a function that modifies the routing table of the malicious node in order for it to forward all the packets (except for DIO, DAO and DIS packets) to another malicious node of my choice creating a tunnel between this two nodes.